# Use Windows-Only Hardware on Mac

Tags: macos, windows, hardware, driver, compatibility

I recently bought [hardware](http://manhattan-products.com/usb-game-port-adapter) that apparently does not support Mac.
When connecting it to my Windows VirtualMachine the installer pops up and the device is ready to be used. However, that does not happen on my Mac (Mac Mini Late 2012, macOS 10.11.2).
I checked for available drivers for the hardware that I could install on my Mac to make it run but they do not offer any.

Is there any application or 3rd party software that allows me to run Windows-only hardware on my Mac?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As we have no idea what the 'hardware' is, there's very little anyone can say right now. Could you edit your question to add further detail?

Comment: Yup, edited. @Tetsujin

Comment: I do hope I'm wrong, but as Mac has never had a game port [which would make me wonder what you would use it for if you ever got it going, as no game made for Mac would ever have been built to support it] & the last actual drivers for that device were made for WinXP... I do think you're rather going to be out of luck.

Comment: @Tetsujin, you are wrong in this case. I bought a def. compatible [controller](http://www.chproducts.com/Flight-Sim-Yoke-v13-d-705.html). On the website it lists Mac OS X under **key features**. I assume that *just* the usb adapter is not compatible.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Mac program with the best chance of working with that accessory would be [GamePad Companion](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/6528/gamepad-companion).

I can't say for sure if it would work with that device, because it is not on the compatibility list, but GamePad Companion probably works with a wider variety of controllers than any other Mac program, and it has the ability to map gamepads to various keyboard and mouse actions so they will work with any game.

(This is my personal opinion, and I am not affiliated with this developer.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I think the app you're linking to deals with game pads rather than the usb game **port**. The game pad is compatible with Mac, while the port which is between the Mac and the game pad is not.